# iOS encryption AES128/CBC/nopadding why is not working?

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

I have an app that needs to encode some data using AES/CBC/no padding. The app is ported also on android. There the encoding is done like this:

```
byte[] encodedKey = getKey();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, "AES");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, paramSpec);

    int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
    int diffSize = decrypted.length % blockSize;
    System.out.println("Cipher size: " + blockSize);
    System.out.println("Current size: " + decrypted.length);
    if (diffSize != 0) {
      diffSize = blockSize - diffSize;
      byte[] oldDecrypted = decrypted;
      decrypted = new byte[decrypted.length + diffSize];
      System.arraycopy(oldDecrypted, 0, decrypted, 0, oldDecrypted.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < diffSize; i++) {
        decrypted[i + oldDecrypted.length] = " ".getBytes()[0];
      }
      System.out.println("New size: " + decrypted.length);

    }
    return cipher.doFinal(decrypted);
```

the initializationVector looks like this:

```
private byte[] initializationVector = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

on iOS i have something like this for encryption:

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key 
{
    // 'key' should be 16 bytes for AES128, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)


    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, 
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128, 
                                          0x0000,
                                          keyPtr, 
                                          kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

the method described above is part of a category over NSData.
the method is called like this:

```
NSData *data = [@"4915200456727" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *cipher  = [data AES128EncryptWithKey:@"@x#zddXekZerBBw6"];
    NSString *ecriptedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [cipher length], [cipher bytes]];
```

the problem that i have is that i don't receive the same encrypted data on iOS and android. On iOS the encrypted data has 0 bytes in length.

Could you give any pointers on how to encrypt a string using AES128 with CBC and no padding and perhaps an example?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. In order to make the encryption work without padding i had to add 0x0000 instead of kCCOptionPKCS7Padding or kCCOptionECBMode which are treated.

Also if the data that needs to be encoded doesn't have a length multiple of kCCKeySizeAES128 ( 16 ) then the vector that holds the data must be resized to have the length multiple with kCCKeySizeAES128 and the empty values filled with something. I added spaces.

```
    - (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));

    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    int dataLength = [self length];
    int diff = kCCKeySizeAES128 - (dataLength % kCCKeySizeAES128);
    int newSize = 0;

    if(diff > 0)
    {
        newSize = dataLength + diff;
    }

    char dataPtr[newSize];
    memcpy(dataPtr, [self bytes], [self length]);
    for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
    {
        dataPtr[i + dataLength] = 0x20;
    }

    size_t bufferSize = newSize + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          0x0000, //No padding
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL,
                                          dataPtr,
                                          sizeof(dataPtr),
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if(cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Padding schemes do not exist for nothing. If your plain data ends with the same value as the padding byte, your own scheme will fail. You should use PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding instead. Depending on your need you should also have integrity protection added (AESCMAC, HMAC or GCM mode encryption).

Comment: the problem is that the server side is already implemented using AES128/CBC/no padding and won't be modified to accept padding. I know that padding doesn't exist for nothing but in this case the chance that the data needed to be encrypted will end with the padding byte is really small to 0.

Comment: OK, that's fine then, but keep in mind: a million-to-one chance succeeds nine times out of ten (Terry Pratchett). Be sure to document this "feature".

Comment: This fails for me 1 out of 3 times. Won't work in a commercial app. Has anyone tried the http://www.example-code.com/objc/crypt2_aes.asp?

Comment: It seems the padded content has influence on the final result, I had to add 0x00 for the padding rather than spaces (0x20). With that, I get the same result as the Java (backend) implementation using Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");