# AES256 decryption on iOS with iso10126 padding

Tags: ios, aes, padding

I need to be able to decrypt a chunk of AES256 encrypted data with iso10126 padding from an uncontrolled server. CCCrypt seems to only support "kCCOptionECBMode" and "kCCOptionPKCS7Padding" as options, so the CommonCrypto library seems incapable of what I want. What is the best solution?

I would also like to be able to use iso7816 and iso10126 padding, but they are less of a priority. I know these padding options were deemed "possibly insecure", but as I can't control the data source, I would like to be able to decrypt with these settings still.

I'm fairly certain these AES encrypted pieces of data are encrypted by the CryptoJS javascript library, (it has all of the padding options mentioned above). I'm aware that I can use this library through a UIWebView and get the result back in Objective-C, but I'd like more speed than what the javascript library can offer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding is one of these things that you can actually program yourself (unlike many other cryptographic algorithms). Just decrypt without any padding, and do the unpadding yourself to get the plain text. If you encrypt, obviously first pad, then encrypt. Almost all libraries support something like "NoPadding". You can simply find how all padding modes work by looking at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)).

Be careful that you always pad/unpad for your given modes. So you may have to add a full block of padding bytes.

Note that ISO 7816 padding does not really exist. It is ISO/IEC 9797-1 Padding Method 2, which is used on bytes instead of any number of bits. The fact that it is used (not defined) in ISO/IEC 7816-4 for secure messaging (informative) does not make it part of that standard.

Other question/answer for no padding:
[iOS encryption AES128/CBC/nopadding why is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900894/ios-encryption-aes128-cbc-nopadding-why-is-not-working)
this link should show you how to perform no padding encryption/decryption using the iOS API.

Comment: Actually edited the wikipedia page to improve (the readability) of it :)